# How Push Notification Services really work?

Tags: push-notification, push

I am trying to understand how exactly push notification services work.
Are these real push services with constant connection to server or just mimics by polling?
How does a server with heavy traffic maintain so many connections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general push notifications work both by establishing a long-lived TCP connection, or using long-polling. The maximum number of connected clients is determined by the server resources.

Take a look at the [Socket.io protocol](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-spec) stack for an example. Or better yet, at the [XMPP/Jabber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP) protocol, which relies on TCP principally and falls back on long polling.

Answer (score 1):

Fusio is correct. For mobile phones, a single push service is typically used (Google cloud messaging for android, Apple Push Notification Service for Apple/iPhone) to limit the amount of connections from the phone. 3rd party applications register to these services and push messages through them.